# Postgresql order by and limit

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table R from which want to select the 3 predecessors or successor based on the z column. I have a btree index over the z column.

```
SELECT key, z, x, y FROM R
    WHERE z <= some_value
    ORDER BY z DESC 
    LIMIT 3
```

retrieves the predecessors in 'no time' but

```
SELECT key, z, x, y FROM R
    WHERE z >= some_value
    ORDER BY z ASC
    LIMIT 3
```

is useless for retrieving the next entries because is starts to scan through all the rows that have z >= some_value. Explain gives identical explanations on how the query is satisfied.
Why is this and what could I do about it?

EDIT:
There are two indexes actually, one ascending and one descending.
Explain for both queries above says:
"Limit  (cost=0.00..31.91 rows=3 width=20)"
"  ->  Index Scan Backward using zreverse on r  (cost=0.00..17727815.24 rows=1666667 width=20)"
"        Filter: (z >= some_value")

Comment: Could you post us the output of EXPLAIN for both of these queries? See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html on how to use this command.

Comment: Did you try `explain analyze` in instead of just `explain`?

Comment: The problem was with the simple function used to calculate some_value omitted here for clarity... It was defined volatile which caused it to be calculated for each row separately.

Answer (score 3):

Uhm...

some_value used in the WHERE clause is calculated by a simple function which was (falsely) defined VOLATILE. Changing it to STABLE solved the issue.

Comment: Great to know this: According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html the optimizer makes no assumptions about values returned from functions marked as volatile and executes this function once for each row. If marked as stable, the optimizer knows that the value returned will be the same for identical input and can optimize away the execution of the function -- eg for index scan.

Answer (score 1):

Is the index on z an "ordinary" btree index with nothing else specified? Or was it created in "descending" order, ie as

```
create index <name> on R(z) desc;
```

?

Quite possibly the addition of the opposite order index to the one you have may help.